# Why dark theme isn't working after using provider and using sharedpreferences?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I wanted to add dark theme in my flutter application. So I read [this](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/implement-dark-mode-in-flutter-using-provider-158925112bf9) article. I followed every steps but the provider seems not working. And my application is behaving weirdly.
Here is my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:arithmatic_calculator/dark_theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:arithmatic_calculator/dark_theme_styles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static const appTitle = "Simple Calculator";
  DarkThemeProvider themeProvider = DarkThemeProvider();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentAppTheme();
  }

  void getCurrentAppTheme() async {
    themeProvider.darkTheme =
        await themeProvider.darkThemePreference.getTheme();
    print(themeProvider.darkTheme);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) {
        print("ChangeNotifier: $themeProvider.darkTheme");
        return themeProvider;
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: Styles.themeData(themeProvider.darkTheme, context),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text(appTitle),
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: const CalculatorHomePage()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CalculatorHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalculatorHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CalculatorHomePage> createState() => _CalculatorHomePageState();
}

class _CalculatorHomePageState extends State<CalculatorHomePage> {
  var num1 = 0, num2 = 0, sum = 0;

  final TextEditingController t1 = TextEditingController(text: "0");
  final TextEditingController t2 = TextEditingController(text: "0");

  void doAddition() {
    setState(() {
      num1 = int.parse(t1.text);
      num2 = int.parse(t2.text);
      sum = num1 + num2;
    });
  }

  void doSub() {
    setState(() {
      num1 = int.parse(t1.text);
      num2 = int.parse(t2.text);
      sum = num1 - num2;
    });
  }

  void doMul() {
    setState(() {
      num1 = int.parse(t1.text);
      num2 = int.parse(t2.text);
      sum = num1 * num2;
    });
  }

  void doDiv() {
    setState(() {
      num1 = int.parse(t1.text);
      num2 = int.parse(t2.text);
      sum = num1 ~/ num2;
    });
  }

  void doClear() {
    setState(() {
      t1.text = "0";
      t2.text = "0";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeChange = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Checkbox(
              value: themeChange.darkTheme,
              onChanged: (bool? val) {
                setState(() {
                  themeChange.darkTheme = val!;
                  print(themeChange.darkTheme);
                });
              }),
          Text(
            "Output: $sum",
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.purple),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
            child: TextField(
              controller: t1,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: "Enter number 1"),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
            child: TextField(
              controller: t2,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: "Enter number 2"),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
                child: MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: doAddition,
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  child: const Text(
                    "ADD",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
                child: MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    doSub();
                  },
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  child: const Text(
                    "SUBTRACT",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
                child: MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    doDiv();
                  },
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  child: const Text(
                    "DIVIDE",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
                child: MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    doMul();
                  },
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  child: const Text(
                    "MULTIPLY",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                doClear();
              },
              color: Colors.purple,
              child: const Text(
                "CLEAR",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my dark_theme_provider.dart:

```
import 'package:arithmatic_calculator/save_theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DarkThemeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  DarkThemePreference darkThemePreference = DarkThemePreference();
  bool _darkTheme = false;
  bool get darkTheme => _darkTheme;
  set darkTheme(bool value) {
    _darkTheme = value;
    darkThemePreference.setDarkTheme(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And here is my save_theme.dart where we used sharedpreferences for saving the current theme.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class DarkThemePreference {
  static const THEME_STATUS = "THEMESTATUS";

  setDarkTheme(bool value) async {
    print("Shared Prefs");
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.setBool(THEME_STATUS, value);
  }

  Future<bool> getTheme() async {
    print("Get theme dhukse");
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getBool(THEME_STATUS) ?? false;
  }
}
```

Can you help me where I am doing wrong? I don't know much about provider.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ChangeNotifierProvider` will look like this. reference

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) {
          return themeChangeProvider;
        },
        child: Consumer<DarkThemeProvider>(
          builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget child) {
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: Styles.themeData(themeChangeProvider.darkTheme, context),
              home: SplashScreen(),
              routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
                AGENDA: (BuildContext context) => AgendaScreen(),
              },
            );
          },
        ),);
```